# How can I grab the current url and assign it to a variable using vb and asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, url, vbscript

I have a form that the user fills out and submits.  I have vb code that converts that form into an email and sends it to me.  I need to know what page it is coming from so I want to assign the current url to a variable that will be included in the email.

Simply put: How do I assign the URL to a variable?

Comment: Is this VB.NET? VBSCRIPT? VB6?

Comment: How are you using VBSCRIPT with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the request object.  e.g. `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

```
Dim url As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the following error,
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Request.Url'

/us_formToEmail_test.asp, line 21

Comment: Did you mean ASP (Classic) and not ASP.NET as the tags specify in your question?

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET
'static variable

```
Private Shared prevPage As String = String.Empty

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually found another solution...  MySite = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

Comment: The only problem with this is that it only returns the domain and not the actual page.  I also tried ("PATH_INFO") but that returned the asp page and not the page the form was on.